# How do I make a deep link for meteor cordova app?

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, deep-linking, url-scheme

I need help with deep linking in meteor cordova app. I need a deep link that will open a specific route in my app through webview and not the browser.

So far I've managed to create a deep link to a root route in my app, but I'm stuck on redirecting it to a specific page/route.

Here is the code I have so far:

mobile-config.js:

```
App.configurePlugin('cordova-plugin-customurlscheme', {
    URL_SCHEME: 'smartpiggybank'
});
```

client/startup.js:

```
handleOpenUrl = function handleOpenURL(url) {
            const token = url.replace("smartpiggybank://intesaSuccess", "https://backdashboard.smartshopping.network");
            console.log("Token: " + token);
            FlowRouter.go('/outletLast');
        }
```

Router: FlowRouter,

[Cordova plugin for custom URL](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme)